# how to deserilize JSON with dynamic numeric field names, using GSON?

Tags: java, json, gson

I have a JSON file in this format:

```
 title 1
 {
    "0" : 2,
    "1" : 5,
    "2" : 8        
  }
 title 2
 {        
    "1" : 44,
    "2" : 15,
    "3" : 73,
    "4" : 41
 }
```

As you can see the indexes are dynamic - in title 1 they were: "0","1","2" and for title 2 they are: "1","2","3","4"

I don't know how to read this using GSON.
I need to somehow convert it into a java object so I can go on and process the data.
Any help is most welcome.

Comment: Why do you need java object? I'd rather convert it to `Map` and used it as map, not as special java object.

Comment: how do I convert it to MAP?

Answer (score 0):

First thing is the JSON that is represented on the page is not valid JSON invalid, so my recommendation is based on the fallowing JSON. Just giving you full disclosure.

```
{
   "title 1":{
      "0":2,
      "1":5,
      "2":8
   },
   "title 2":{
      "1":44,
      "2":15,
      "3":73,
      "4":41
   }
}
```

OPTION 1 (not how i would solve this issue)

This would serialize it as a general object that you could loop threw to process.

```
new Gson().fromJson(yourJsonString,Object.class);
```

OPTION 2 (best bet in my opinion)
If you had control of how the object cam in i would do something like this

```
{
   "listOfTitles":[
      {
         "title":[
            {
               "key":"0",
               "value":1234
            },
            {
               "key":"1",
               "value":12341234
            },
            {
               "key":"2",
               "value":123412341234
            }
         ],
         "titleName":"title 1"
      },
      {
         "title":[
            {
               "key":"0",
               "value":12341
            },
            {
               "key":"1",
               "value":123412
            },
            {
               "key":"2",
               "value":12
            },
            {
               "key":"3",
               "value":12341
            }
         ],
         "titleName":"title 2"
      }
   ]
}
```

This would allow for you to build an object like...

```
public class YouObjectName{
   private ArrayList<Title> listOfTitles;
   private String titleName;
   //constructor

   //getters and setters
}

public class Title{
   private String key;

   private Integer value;

   //constructor

   //getters and setters
}
```

I would consume this with GSON like

```
new Gson().fromJson(jsonString,YouObjectName.class);
```

Hope that helps a little.